# Elastic search + translated content in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch

I would like to setup ElasticSearch on a table "content" which also have translation table "content_translation" for localization purpose (Globalize gem). We have 10 languages.

I want to implement Elasticsearch for my data model. In SQL I would search like:

```
SELECT id, content_translation.content 
FROM content 
LEFT JOIN content_translation on content.id = content_translation.content_id
WHERE content_translation.content LIKE '%???????%'
```

I wonder what is the best strategy to do "left join" like search with ElasticSearch?

Should I create just "content" index with all translation data in it?

```
{"id":21, "translations":{"en":{"content":"Lorem..."}, "de":{"content":"Lorem..."} ..}
```

Should I create "content_translation" index and just filter results for specific locale?

```
{"content_id":21, "locale":"en", "content": "Lorem ..."}
```

Are there some good practices how to do it?

Should I take care of maintaining index by myself or should I use something like "Tire gem" which takes care about indexing by itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend the second alternative (one document per language), assuming that you wouldn't need to show content from multiple languages.

i.e.

```
{"content_id":21, "locale":"en", "content": "Lorem ..."}
```

I recommend a gem like `Tire`, and exploit it's DSL to your advantage.

You could have your content model to look like:

```
class Content < ActiveRecord:Base

    include Tire::Model::Search
    include Tire::Model::Callbacks

    ...

end
```

Then you could do have a search method that would do something like

```
Content.search do
    query do
        ...
    end
    filter :terms, :locale => I18n.locale.to_s
end
```

Your application would need to maintain `locale` at all times, to serve the respective localized content. You could just use `I18n`'s locale and look up data. Just pass this in as a filter and you could have the separation you wish. Bonus is, you get fallback for free if you have enabled it in `i18n` for rails.

However, if you have a use case where you need to show multi-lingual content side by side, then this fails and you could look at a single document holding all language content.